# The tag wiki for Java sounds like a broken sentence

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

> Java is a commonly used programming language, plus the ecosystem allowing Java programs to run unchanged on almost any hardware and software platform. See "about the java tag" for initial help.

From the top of this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: By the way, I like the stackoverflow tag wiki: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/info

Comment: yeah that one is pretty funny.

Comment: Can we protect that SO tag from vandalism? Funny might become a crime in the future on SO.

Comment: @abel: What's your point?

Comment: The [SO Tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/info) is funny. With things becoming stricter and funny posts being "frowned" upon, that Tag wiki could go the way of the dodo.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed, I think.

Let me know if you'd suggest any changes.  I tried to preserve the initial meaning.

> Java is a commonly used programming language. It is popular because Java programs are designed to run unchanged on almost any hardware and software platform. Java also refers to the Java Virtual Machine which is used to run Java programs. See "about the java tag" for initial help.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info

Comment: I thought **we** were fast to fix things. 3 minutes... hard to beat!

Comment: @George, kinda bored at work right now.  Lots of time to kill.

Comment: That is a muchly better sentence, plus the phrasing makes me better to understand.

Comment: @Bill, thanks.  I've been using English for about 23 years now; I hope I've gotten good at it. `;)`

Comment: @Justin, good effort, but you dropped a point. The original mentioned that "Java" also refers to the platform (or "ecosystem") that the Java language uses. Not sure if that was intentional on your part.

Comment: @Pop, added JVM info...better?

Comment: @Justin, Popular Demand approves of your edit.